# strange numeric output rmarkdown r

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having problems with numeric format in rmarkdown. Here's my sample code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "10/8/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
num <- 11111
```

here is the number: `r num`
````

Heres the output I get:

```
  Untitled
me

10/8/2017

here is the number: 1.111110^{4}
```

I want this output:

```
Untitled
me

10/8/2017

here is the number: 11111
```

Comment: If you try different values with one more digit each time: 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, you'll see that scientific notation "kicks in" at 11111. This is controlled by `options(scipen = n)`, where `n = 0` by default and larger values for `n` suppress scientific notation. See `?options`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply replace `num <- 11111` with `num <- 11111L`, i.e., specify `num` to be an integer.